# JSP not picking up CSS file

Tags: css, eclipse, jsp

I have created a simple Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse Mars, using Spring. My JSP is referring to a CSS file but css file is not getting pickup.

Eclipse Project Folder Structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srh2K.png)

Here is how, I referring it in my JSP:

Comment: href="/css/anotherStylesheet.css"

Answer (score 0):

My project structure is same as yours and I refer css file via:

`href="css/anotherStylesheet.css"`

Answer (score 0):

Use this to add the css file

```
<link href="folder/styleFile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

It may also work when you drag and drop the CSS file directly to your page.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your help! I tried both ways, it didn't work.
First time I got :  "WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/FirstSpringMVCPrj/css/anotherStylesheet.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'FirstSpringMVCPrj'"
second time (when I dragged and dropped):WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/FirstSpringMVCPrj/WebContent/css/anotherStylesheet.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'FirstSpringMVCPrj'

Comment: First you need to declare your resources in dispatcher-servlet file like this :

`<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/folder/" />`
Any request with url mapping /resources/** will directly look for /resources/folder/.

Now in jsp file you need to include your css file like this :

`<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/main.css" />" rel="stylesheet">`
Similarly you can include js files.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the spring.xml and add the css folder in the configuration.Also check the eclipse deployment assembly (include the your webcontent floder)